# strange null question

Tags: php, null

I want to use such code:

```
$arr=array('a'=>$a);
```

but `$a` is not defined, so I get error. But if I write this code before

```
if (!isset($a))
$a=null;
```

all works. Why? In the beginning `$a` is not defined , so `$a=null`. or `underfined!=NULL` ?

Comment: try with `var_dump($a)`;

Comment: i get Undefined variable

Comment: null and undefined are 2 different things

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write

```
array("a"=>$a)
```

it means that you want the key "a" refers to a variable reference named $a which does not exist in the first place thus you are getting an error; but when you add

```
$a=null;
```

before hand, although you are setting $a to null but actually you are creating a variable reference named $a that's known by PHP so there will be no errors.

Comment: In other words, PHP has an internal table of all the variables and their values (well, several tables actually, one for each function scope, but that's besides the point). When your code does something to a variable, PHP looks in the table to find its value. If it's not there, you get the error, and the value is assumed to be `null`. But `$a=null` adds the variable name to the table and sets the value explicitly to `null`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in truth `undefined` != `null`, although the difference is only in the eyes of PHP when it decides whether to throw an error or not. Otherwise it's the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

As you already discovered undefined is different from null.

Undefined means that the name $a in not yet into the scope of your function/code.
`$a=null` is a (no)value assigned to a variable.

By the way you should get a Notice, not an error as using undefined variables as right-values php warns you about a probable typo and proceed with the script execution.

As a rule of thumb, if you address an undefined variable on the left of the assignment (=) simbol (a left-value name) then php create a new variables name and bind it into the current scope, if the reference is on the right (are you using the value contained instead than the variable itself) php warns you and keep going. You can change this behaviour by the [error_reporting](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)  function.

Answer (score -1):

see the [manual of isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

> Returns TRUE if var exists and has
>   value other than NULL, FALSE
>   otherwise.